# Google BigQuery WRITE_TRUNCATE erasing all data

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery

I have a table setup in BQ where if I write data that `exists` on a certain date partition I want it to overwrite.  I've set up the job_config to use WRITE_TRUNCATE.

```
#file_obj = Some ndjson StringIO file like obj

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
# Set configuration.query.destinationTable
dest_dataset = 'test'
dest_table_name = 'sales_data'
destination_dataset = client.dataset(dest_dataset)
destination_table = destination_dataset.table(dest_table_name)
job_config.destination = destination_table

# Set configuration.query.writeDisposition & SourceFormat
job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON

# Set partitioning
time_partitioning = bigquery.table.TimePartitioning(
    bigquery.table.TimePartitioningType.DAY, 'date'
)
job_config.time_partitioning = time_partitioning

# Start the load job
job = client.load_table_from_file(
        file_obj, destination_table,
        job_config=job_config
)
# Wait for the job to finish
job.result()
```

However, I noticed that when I backfilled data it always overwrites all data in the table even if the date partition is different.  For example if I have data in the table from `20190101-20190201` and I load data from `20190202-Present` my whole table gets erased and it only includes the new data.  Shouldn't this data remain preserved since it's on a different partition date?  Any idea why this is happening or if I'm missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Any idea why this is happening or if I'm missing something?

job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE' is the whole table scope action - and says `If the table already exists - overwrites the table data.` This does not consider any partitioning and affects the whole table

If you need to overwrite specific partition you need to specifically reference this partition - for example as `sales_data$20190202`

Comment: So for example if I have 3 years worth of data to load starting from for example `20190424` back to `20160424` what date would be put at the end for the partition decorator?  Would it be `sales_data$20190424`?  Sorry I'm sort of new to this whole concept.  Basically I want to keep in tact historical data on a rolling basis and only overwrite data with the same date.. So tomorrow when running the api I would want to only overwrite any data that is already in the table for a certain day... if that day is not in the table then keep it as is.

Comment: Also for the partition decorator overwrite, would I still want to use `WRITE_TRUNCATE` or  something else?

Comment: I submitted another question if you could please take a look